# Aggreate in MongoDb for documents embedded in list of values

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have in MongDb data as below

```
{
        "_id" : 7,
        "name" : "Salena Olmos",
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : 90.37826509157176
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 42.48780666956811
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 67.18328596625217
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 96.52986171633331
                }
        ]
}
```

all I want to sum "scores" for "type" : "homework" as

```
{ "_id" : 7, "score" : 163.71314768258548}
```

I have written my query using aggregate and filter condition as below

```
db.students.aggregate([
    {     
     "$group" : 
      { 
       "_id":"$_id",
       "score":{$sum: {$filter: {
                                input: "$scores",
                                    as: "x",
                                cond: {$eq : ["$$x.type", "homework"]}
                                }
                      }
               }
      }
    }
])
```

but all it gives me as "0" as sum value as :

```
{ "_id" : 7, "score" : 0 }
```

Please help me , I am new to MongoDb and trying to learn by solving some exercise problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation. Use [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to extract the score from matching scores.

```
db.students.aggregate({
  "$project":{
    "score":{
      "$sum":{
        "$let":{
          "vars":{
            "mscores":{
              "$filter":{
                "input":"$scores",
                "as":"x",
                "cond":{"$eq":["$$x.type","homework"]}
              }
            }
          },
          "in":"$$mscores.score"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: woo.. whats wrong with my query , I have to clear my concepts also.

Comment: can I use unwind also ? please suggest

Comment: Yes you can but it is not needed in your case. You missed the part of mapping the  score value which is what I did inside $let expression.

Comment: I found one more way .
db.students.aggregate([ 
   {$unwind: "$scores"},
   {$match:{"scores.type" : "homework"}},
   {$group : {"_id":"$_id", "score":{$sum: "$scores.score"}}}
 ])

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the MongoDb docs and come up with below solution

```
  db.students.aggregate([ 
   {$unwind: "$scores"},
   {$match:{"scores.type" : "homework"}},
   {$group : {"_id":"$_id", "score":{$sum: "$scores.score"}}}
 ])
```